# iOS: Getting JSON cell value

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

So I am loading information via JSON to a table view in my iOS app.  When you click on one of the table cells, I need to get the "id" of the story in the database, from the cell clicked.

I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know where to start.

Comment: No, it's not "Xcode", it's iOS or "the Cocoa Touch API"...

Comment: "I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know where to start." Do you have the table created? The cell click functionality? The database set up? The app created? Are you only wondering about loading JSON objects or are you looking for information on developing the entire application?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know where to start, start at the beginning. How 'bout a tutorial on using JSON in iOS? The Ray Wenderlich website has great tutorials. http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

> OS 5 has some new built-in APIs to make it really easy to read and
>   write JSON.
>
> If you don’t know what JSON is, it’s a simple human readable format
>   that is often used to send data over a network connection.
>
> For example, if you have an array of three strings, the JSON
>   representation would simply be:
>
> ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
>
> If you have a Pet object with member variables name, breed, and age,
>   the JSON representation would simply be:
>
> {"name" : "Dusty", "breed": "Poodle", "age": 7}
>
> It’s that simple, which is why it’s so easy and popular to use. For
>   the full spec, which can be read in just a couple minutes, check out
>   www.json.org.

Answer (score 0):

You must be feeding the table with data from somewhere, so let's assume that that's an `NSArray` of `Story` objects.

When you select a row in a tableView, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method will be called. The `tableView` supplies the `indexPath` of the selected row.

An `NSIndexPath` has two properties - `section` and `row`. The `indexPath.row` value of the selected cell will correspond to the index of the element of the `NSArray` from which the cell got the `Story` object. So if you want to retrieve the `Story` for the tapped row, you'd use `[theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`